# How to make pairs of strings that are contained in a list and display each string in columns of jTable? [Java Swing]

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a game registration and matchmaking system. I am able to register people in my MySQL database. I can get all name values in my database column into a list and shuffle it. Now I want to the strings in the list to display alternately in my jtable which has 2 columns. Example: I have James, Harry, Ali, Sinclair, Bob in my list. I shuffle it. Then I want to display in jtable like:
Column 1 contains James, Column 2 contains Harry, then again Column 1 contains Ali and Column 2 contains Sinclair. Like that.  Hope I have been clear.
 I have tried:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    String category = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = DBC.getData("Select * from main where c_category='" + category + "'");
        while(rs.next()){
            names.add(rs.getString("c_name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MatchMake.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(names);
    Collections.shuffle(names);
    System.out.println(names);
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    dtm.addRow(new Object[]{names});
```

but it doesnt give the desired result. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What if you have three items?

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Tried to create your own `TableModel`?

Comment: Its there, dtm.

Comment: @CodeMan in your example you have 4 people and you can split them easily split them into two columns as 4 can be divided by two with no remainder. How your app should behave if your query returns odd number of items?

Comment: I meant implementing your own `TableModel`? BTW, you could just build a 2 dimensional array of your names, and use it to create your `DefaultTableModel`...

Comment: Since you want to add more than one row, don’t you think you’ll need a loop, in whose body you call `dtm.addRow`?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Could u please provide code snippets?

Comment: @AlexeyR. If it returns an odd number then surely one part in the row will be left, then ill find someone else to play with him xD